# lstlisting space symbol problem in R code

Tags: listings

I am using the package `listings`. I was writing some code of R in LaTeX. I followed the suggestions from @Alan Munn by using `showstringspaces=false`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen}
    showstringspaces=false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#Bar plot Top U.S. imports from Canada
us_canada_import <- data.frame(Activities=c('Mineral Fuels',
'Vehicles','Machinery','Special Other (returns)',
                       'Plastics', 'Rest of Economic Activities'),
                               Revenue=c(85,53,23,16,12,129.8))

us_canada_import_chart <- us_canada_import %>% 
  group_by(Activities) %>%
  summarize(sum_revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
  mutate(percent = sum_revenue/sum(sum_revenue), cum_sum = cumsum(sum_revenue)) %>%
  arrange(sum_revenue) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x='U.S. imports from Canada', y=sum_revenue, fill=Activities))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", percent*100),"%")), 
            position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")+
  ggtitle("Segmentation U.S. top imports from Canada 2018") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Revenue in billions of U.S. dollars")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

However, every time I write a string with spaces, the symbol

[image]

appears instead of space. However, when I write a comment the symbol

[image]

appears instead.

[image]

How can I make comments and strings using space, but without getting these problems?

Comment: You're missing the comma to separate the `showstringsspaces` key from the previous keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a display option for `listings` called `showstringspaces`. Set this to `false` and the spaces will appear as you want them to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    showstringspaces=false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
us_canada_import <- data.frame(Activities=c('Mineral Fuels',
'Vehicles','Machinery','Special Other (returns)',
                       'Plastics', 'Rest of Economic Activities'),
                               Revenue=c(85,53,23,16,12,129.8))

us_canada_import_chart <- us_canada_import %>% 
  group_by(Activities) %>%
  summarize(sum_revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
  mutate(percent = sum_revenue/sum(sum_revenue), cum_sum = cumsum(sum_revenue)) %>%
  arrange(sum_revenue) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x='U.S. imports from Canada', y=sum_revenue, fill=Activities))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", percent*100),"%")), 
            position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")+
  ggtitle("Segmentation U.S. top imports from Canada 2018") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Revenue in billions of U.S. dollars")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer I used your suggestion. However, the problem persists, and a new issue appears. I edited my question to point out your suggestion and the new problems that appear.

Comment: I also updated listing, and listings package, but it seems this is not the issue.

Comment: @Ivan You're missing a comma before the `showstringsspaces` in your updated code. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. @Alan Munn, thanks for the feedback.